# How to easily install any GPG GUI on Ubuntu that actually works?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, gnupg

I am trying to install any GnuPG GUI for easy encryption/decryption of text, and I feel like I am in bizarro world where nothing works at all. On Mac OS X, I use [GPGTools](https://gpgtools.org/) and it works flawlessly, so I thought it will be similar on Ubuntu, but no such luck so far.

What I tried so far:

- [GPA](https://www.gnupg.org/%28de%29/related_software/gpa/index.html) - it just starts, shows no less than 3 error messages on top of each other, and does nothing (doesn't even displays the keys I imported into gpg through bash).
- [KGPG](https://utils.kde.org/projects/kgpg) - install tons of KDE packages through `apt-get`, and then it never starts anyway. I managed to get it to start once, but never again.
- [Seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse) - finally something that actually starts and shows my keys, but I can't find a way to do anything with them (encrypt or decrypt). Nothing shows up in any Nautilus menu. I have installed `gedit-plugins`, but nothing like GPG or Seahorse plugin shows up in gedit plugin list.

What are my other options?

(Note: I specifically don't want to use a mail client with GPG supoprt, I just want to encrypt and decrypt text files.)

Comment: There is Kleopatra, but I've not tested it on Ubuntu.  There's also [gpg4usb](http://gpg4usb.org/) which I've used to encrypt/decrypt messages, but I store my private keys on an encrypted USB drive inside gpg4usb for those purposes.

Comment: See also on [softwarerecs.se]: [GnuPG-aware GUI to encrypt/decrypt PGP ASCII on Linux](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11254/60), where [**pyrite** was recommended](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11308/60).

Comment: https://gnupg.org/software/frontends.html

Answer (score 9):

Besides Seahorse, which is only the key manager, you need a package called `seahorse-nautilus` to be able to encrypt/decrypt files with Nautilus.

It adds a menu item to the right-click context menu that allows you to encrypt a file directly from the file manager.

**Note:** This is the package name in Ubuntu 14.04. Other versions may have a different package name.

**Additional Note:** It may be required to log out of the current session and re-login for everything to work properly after installing the required packages.

Answer (score 0):

I got KGpg to to work.

Downloaded it from Ubuntu Software Center

I found in the reviews section a tweak to make it work, follow instructions here:

http://do-the-right-things.blogspot.com/2012/12/cavaet-in-using-kgpg-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

I use Seahorse in combination with plugins for gedit and Nautilus. The easiest way to import keys I've found is to save the public key in a text file with the extension .asc and then double-click on it.

For Nautilus on ubuntu the package is called `seahorse-nautilus`, this adds an encrypt option when you right-click on a file in the file manager.

For gedit you install the plugin available on this site: https://pietrobattiston.it/gedit-crypto
This adds encrypt and decrypt options to the menu in gedit.

Comment: Unfortunately this is 2014 question, I moved back to Mac in 2019.

Comment: sure, but for others who end up here thanks to google it might be useful

Comment: yep, it might! I just cannot accept/vote